# Passing multiple string through intent and displaying them

Tags: android-intent

I am a beginner in developing android apps and i have a homework so i need your help .
i want to pass 3 strings from one activity into second act and then display those strings in the second activity.The user must input the strings .

thats my code i dont know what is the problem .
     Main.java

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class Main extends Activity {

public  static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mobile.activity4.class" ;
public  static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.mobile.activity4.class" ;
public  static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE3 = "com.mobile.activity4.class" ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);


    EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message3);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    String message3 = editText3.getText().toString();

    extras.putString("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
    extras.putString("EXTRA_MESSAGE2",message2);
    extras.putString("EXTRA_MESSAGE3",message3);

    myIntent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(myIntent);



}

  }
```

`

---

DisplayMessageAcivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.view.Menu;
          import android.widget.TextView;

       public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message  =  extras.getString(Main.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message2 = extras.getString(Main.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
    String message3 = extras.getString(Main.EXTRA_MESSAGE3);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);

    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView2.setTextSize(40);
    textView3.setTextSize(40);

    textView.setText(message);
    textView2.setText(message2);
    textView3.setText(message3);

    setContentView(textView);
    setContentView(textView2);
    setContentView(textView3);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

       }
```

---

Please help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What problem you are facing here?

in DisplayMessageActivity, you have to keep all the textview inside the layout and set the layout in the setcontentview as below,

```
      TextView textView = new TextView(this);
      TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
     TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
     LinearLayout linear=new LinearLayout(this);
     linear.addView(textView);
     linear.addView(textView2);
     linear.addView(textView3);

     setContentView(linear);
```

You can done this in xml also

keep all the text view in xml layout and set the layout in setcontentview as

```
       setContentView(R.layout.acitivyt_layout);
```

If you have any doubt let me know.